# Using formula in excel validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a dependent drop down list for my colleagues, where I have one column containing county name, next column containing state name, next customer name & next customer location. I have prepared all the list as per my requirement in the next worksheet named "LIST" in same workbook. In list worksheet customer name & location is combined i.e. "customer name-location". 
while setting up validation I need customer name in separate column & customer location in separate column. I am using below formula in source field of validation window - 
for name

```
LEFT(INDIRECT($B2),SEARCH("-",INDIRECT($B2),1)-1)
```

for location

```
RIGHT(INDIRECT($B2),LEN(INDIRECT($B2))-SEARCH("-",INDIRECT($B2),1))
```

this code is causing error "the list source must be a delimited list or reference to single row or column"

Please help to solve this issue 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error states, this is not possible that way. But `excel dependent dropdown` is probably one of the most discussed Excel themes in the web. So a web search using those key words will be successful. Example result:  http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error message states, your list reference must be a range. This can be a direct reference (e.g., "B2:B5"), a named range, or a range from a function (e.g., `INDIRECT`, `INDEX`, or `OFFSET`).

I would suggest putting your formulas in ranges and pointing to them for the data validation lists. You could also save the formulas as named ranges.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I need more help please, I have set validation in my sheet but want to hide validation option so that no one will be able to see or change what validation I have given in the sheet. OR is there another way to do this.

Comment: Data validation is disabled when you protect a worksheet.